# Hi, I use RichEdit in Delphi 11 but cannot replace a word. SelText always finds the characters in the next line

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, richedit

RichEdit always selects text in next line, replacing the incorrect values.
Marker is a string constant = '/~^&"£$'

```
Assert ( Pos ( marker, RichEdit1.Lines.Text ) = 0 );  // This confirms that there is no marker
RichEdit1.Lines[idx] := Marker +  RichEdit1.Lines[idx]; // First put a marker at beginning of line
MarkerPos1 := Pos ( Marker, RichEdit1.Lines.text ) - 1; // Find the marker
RichEdit1.SetFocus;
RichEdit1.SelStart := Pos ( Marker, RichEdit1.Lines.Text ) - 1; // Now find position of marker => line beginning
RichEdit1.SelLength := Length (  RichEdit1.Lines[idx] );
tmpLine := RichEdit1.SelText;
FontSize := RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Size;                // Get the fontsize
```

TmpLine does not contain the text in RichEdit1.Lines[idx], but the text in the following line.

Some assistance will be appreciated

Comment: Using `Pos()` on `RichEdit.Lines.Text` is very inefficient, and potentially inaccurate due to differences between line break handling of `TStrings` and the underlying RichEdit control. Since you are putting the `Marker` at the front of a line, just ask the RichEdit directly for the actual character index of that specific line by sending it an [`EM_LINEINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-lineindex) mesaage. Also have a look at the [`EM_LINELENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-linelength) message.

Comment: Thank you Remy.  Where can I find information about using SendMessage to communicate with RichEdit.  I have never doen this before and do not see any documentation.  My Google searches also proved fruitless.

Comment: [`SendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) is a Win32 function, so refer to Microsoft's documentation. Use the RichEdit's [`Handle`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Handle) property in the `HWND` parameter. Alternatively, you can use the RichEdit's [`Perform()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform) method instead.